# Help find points of inflection on trig equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**My Attempt**
Okay, so I have the equation  $f(x)=sin(x)+cos(x)$ on interval $[0,2\pi]$
Next, I found first derivative 
$f'(x)=cos(x)-sin(x)=0$
Then, I found second derivative 
$f{"}(x)=-sin(x)-cos(x)=0$
After, I am not so sure what to do with $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: You can turn the two into a single trig function

Comment: Thanks but I'm not that smart 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0=-\sin x-\cos x\iff\sin x=-\cos x\iff\tan x=-1=-\tan\dfrac\pi4=\tan\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

$x=n\pi-\dfrac\pi4$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Much appreciated fam

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is
$$-\sin x-\cos x = 0 \implies \sin^2 x+2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2 x=0\implies 2\sin x \cos x=-1$$
$$\implies \sin 2x=-1\implies\dots$$